# Adding record to table PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So this should be a very simple add to table PHP/MySQL - however for some reason I can't get to work. I have tried playing with the quotes placement, connections, etc. However I think I need some help. Thanks

```
<?php 
//Variables from Form
$Fs = "$_POST[Fs]";
$Ls = "$_POST[Ls]";
$T = "$_POST[T]"; 
$A = "$_POST[A]";
$Sn = "$_POST[Sn]";
?>

<h2>Add</h2>
<form  id="form"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">

<input name="Fs" type="text" value="First Name" size="20" maxlength="60" onfocus="if (this.value=='First Name') this.value='';"onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='First Name';"/>
<input name="Ls" type="text" value="Last Name" size="20" maxlength="60"onfocus="if (this.value=='Last Name') this.value='';"onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Last Name';" />
<input name="T" type="text" value="Telephone" size="20" maxlength="60" onfocus="if (this.value=='Telephone') this.value='';"onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Telephone';"/>
<input name="A" type="text" value="Address" size="20" maxlength="60"onfocus="if (this.value=='Address') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Address';"/>
<input name="Sn" type="text" value="Student Number" size="40" maxlength="40" onfocus="if (this.value=='Student Number') this.value='';" onblur="if (this.value=='') this.value='Student Number';"/>
```

```
 <?php 
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) 
 { 

//Conections

 $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "root") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("assign2") or die(mysql_error());

//Insert Statements

if($Fs != null && $Ls != null && $T != null && $T != null && $A != null && $Sn != null) {
    echo "<br><br><br>" .  $Fs . " " . $Ls . " " . $T . " " . $A . " " . $Sn ;
     mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'assign2table' (First_Name , Last_Name , Telephone , Address ,Student_Number) VALUES ('$Fs' , '$Ls' . '$T' . '$A' . '$Sn')");
 }
else {
echo "Missing Info"; 

  }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Where do you set your variables `$Fs,$Ls,$T,$A,$Sn`??

Comment: You are doing a `mysql_connect`, but trying to use a `mysqli_query` on that `mysql_` connection -> `mysql_` != `mysqli_`

Comment: @Sean I fixed the mysql . still no success.

Comment: I was actually able to fix it. For some reason, instead of dong ($con, ....) .. I removed a variable for that and went straight into it. I don't know the difference. An explanation would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php vs http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php. In `mysql_query()` it is `mysql_query($query, $connection)` where in  `mysqli_query()` it is `mysqli_query($connection, $query)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**YOU have used (DOT) (.) instead of comma(,) in insert query.**

mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'assign2table' (First_Name , Last_Name , Telephone , Address ,Student_Number) VALUES ('$Fs' , '$Ls' , '$T' , '$A' ,'$Sn')");

Comment: Hi Arun , good catch .. Changed that and it's still not working .. also made sure all of them are mysql (not mysqli) ..

Comment: Whether if(isset($_POST['Submit']))  condition is returning true ?

Comment: It is returning true - I was actually able to fix it. For some reason, instead of dong ($con, ....) .. I removed a variable for that and went straight into it. I don't know the difference. An explanation would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all, every time you call a database function you should check its return value to see if it failed. When you don't do it something may fail and you won't have any idea what happened.

That's the case here: you have separated some of the values in the insert statement with dots instead of commas. That's an SQL syntax error. The query should look like:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO 'assign2table' (First_Name , Last_Name , Telephone , Address ,Student_Number) VALUES ('$Fs' , '$Ls', '$T', '$A', '$Sn')");
if ($result === FALSE) {
    echo "Insert failed: ".mysqli_error($con);
}
```

Secondly, this code has a glaring SQL injection vulnerability. You should learn to use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).